# Почему очки в Google Play Leaderboard отличаются если смотреть с другого устройства?

Tags: android, google-play-services

Такая проблема:
В игре интегририрована таблица рекордов из google play services, показывается она стандартным способом.

У игрока на телефоне набраны N очков, отправлены в таблицу, и он видит себя на 10 месте.
С другого телефона если открыть эту таблицу, то первый игрок отображается с M очками на 19 месте.

Т.е. такое ощущение, что первый раз отправились M очков "глобально", и все их видят, а второй раз N очков отправились "локально", и их видит только сам игрок.

Что это может быть, кто-нибудь знает?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: а вы сами все нормально установили код?